# Check if ISO has Joliet extension by DiscUtils

Tags: c#, iso, iso9660

I'm developing a function to verify if the ISO has Joliet extension.
I use DiscUtils to create the ISO file as follow

```
CDBuilder builder = new CDBuilder();
builder.UseJoliet = true;
builder.VolumeIdentifier = "A_SAMPLE_DISK";
builder.AddFile("x/x.png", @"C:\Users\Circle\Pictures\Image 1.png");
builder.Build(@"C:\temp\sample.iso");
```

However, when I read the ISO file. It doesn't be recognized as Joliet

```
using (FileStream isoStream = File.Open(@"C:\temp\sample.iso", FileMode.Open))
{
    CDReader cd = new CDReader(isoStream, true);
    if (cd.ActiveVariant == Iso9660Variant.Joliet)
    {
        // Never enter here
    }
}
```

Not sure which part I did wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be doing it wrong; however the code won't ever set that ActiveVariant.

If you [look at the underlying code](https://github.com/DiscUtils/DiscUtils/blob/master/Library/DiscUtils.Iso9660/VfsCDReader.cs#L134), it seems to switch the `ActiveVariant` to `Iso9660Variant.Iso9660` for joliet extensions for the purposes of that field. I don't know the reason for that - it might be a bug, it might have some other esoteric reason for doing it based on some other code in the project.

I've added a couple of comments to the code, and reproduced it here.

```
case Iso9660Variant.Joliet:
    if (svdPos != 0) // <-- Joliet is always a supplementary table.
    {
        data.Position = svdPos;
        data.Read(buffer, 0, IsoUtilities.SectorSize);
        SupplementaryVolumeDescriptor volDesc = new SupplementaryVolumeDescriptor(buffer, 0);

        Context = new IsoContext { VolumeDescriptor = volDesc, DataStream = _data };
        RootDirectory = new ReaderDirectory(Context,
            new ReaderDirEntry(Context, volDesc.RootDirectory));
        ActiveVariant = Iso9660Variant.Iso9660; // <-- set active variant to base Iso9660
    }

    break;
```